# How to change background in ImageButton

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml

If I try to add backgrounds to 2 or more ImageButton, (**android:background="@string/background"**) the app crashes when the debugger starts the app.
Logcat error message says: run out of memory

Comment: background your loading from drawable or string folder? Share you code

Comment: If you are having an image called background inside your drawable folder and you want to set it as background, I posted the code below, use that  i hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Raw images will harmful for phone memory the easiest way to fix that to use Glide library it is very easy to use
[Glide Library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

After installation you can use it simple

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(R.drawable.resource_id)
    .into(imageButton);
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I install the Library?

Comment: [Glide Installation Guide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/download-setup.html) there is full instruction for installing glide. feel free to ask any questions)

Comment: If I downloaded the file, I got 2 folders (com; META-INF). What I have to do with it?

Comment: You needn’t download it just add to your gradle.build file glide’s depencies

Comment: Van you tell me an Example? 
For Example I have a MyProject app. My ImageButton id is btn1. How can add it to my .java file, amd how can I implement the glade to my Gradle file. I use Android 4.3 to develop, and my phone (that I use to debug) has Android 5.0.3 (21 API level)

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows you are trying to load background from string folder, that's wrong, that's why your app is crashing.

If you are having an image called background inside your drawable folder you can set this image to your buttons like the below code.

```
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button 1"
      android:background="@drawable/background"/>
```

it will work for you.